# convert infix to postfix and calculate

Tags: java

I want to convert an infix expression to a postfix one. With the code below, the expression `25*1-(8+3)/4+2` is converted into `[25, 1, *, -, 8, (, 3, +, 4, /, ), 2, +]` instead of `[25, 1, *, 8, 3, +, 4, /, -, 2, +, ]`

I found some other similar converters in StackOverflow and compared with my source, but I can't find the problem. What is the problem?

```
package calTest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Calc2 {

    private static Stack stack = new Stack();

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String enteredExpression = "25*1-(8+3)/4+2";

        if (!enteredExpression.equals(0)) {
            ArrayList<String> finalExp = converter(enteredExpression);
            //Double result = getResult(finalExp);
            // calModel.setResult(result);
            System.out.println(finalExp);
        } else {
            clear();
        }
    }


    public static ArrayList<String> converter(String enteredExpression) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        System.out.println("enteredExpression : " + enteredExpression);
        String regEx = "(\\d+)|(\\D)";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(enteredExpression);


        ArrayList<String> listMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> finalExp = new ArrayList<String>();


        while (m.find())
            listMatches.add(m.group());

        for (int i = 0; i < listMatches.size(); i++) {

            String numberExp = "(\\d+)";
            Pattern numberP = Pattern.compile(numberExp);
            Matcher numberMatch = numberP.matcher(listMatches.get(i));


            if (numberMatch.find()) {

                finalExp.add(listMatches.get(i));
            } else {

                while (!stack.isEmpty() && getPriority(stack.peek()) >= getPriority(listMatches.get(i))) {

                    finalExp.add(stack.pop());
                }

                stack.push(listMatches.get(i));
            }
        }

        while (!stack.isEmpty())

            finalExp.add(stack.pop());
        return finalExp;

    }

    public static int getPriority(String op) {
        int result = 0;
        switch (op) {
            case "(":
            case ")":
                result = 3;
            case "+":
            case "-":
                result = 1;
                break;
            case "*":
            case "/":
                result = 2;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Double getResult(ArrayList<String> finalExp) {
        Stack<Double> calculateStack = new Stack<Double>();
        Double a;
        Double b;


        for (int i = 0; i < finalExp.size(); i++) {
            String regEx = "(\\d+)";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(finalExp.get(i));


            if (m.find()) {
                calculateStack.push(Double.valueOf(finalExp.get(i)));
            } else {

                switch (finalExp.get(i)) {
                    case "*":
                        b = calculateStack.pop();
                        a = calculateStack.pop();
                        calculateStack.push(Double.valueOf(a * b));
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        b = calculateStack.pop();
                        a = calculateStack.pop();
                        calculateStack.push(Double.valueOf(a / b));
                        break;
                    case "+":
                        b = calculateStack.pop();
                        a = calculateStack.pop();
                        calculateStack.push(Double.valueOf(a + b));
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        b = calculateStack.pop();
                        a = calculateStack.pop();
                        calculateStack.push(Double.valueOf(a - b));
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
        return calculateStack.pop();
    }

    public static void clear() {
    }
}
```

Comment: 'What is the problem' is not enough for problem definition. Do not expect community to finish your homework! If you have specific problem (expected result, actual result) then edit your question.

Comment: You are missing break in the "getPriority" method case "(" ")" 
And pop the stack until the first "(" when you get the ")" right parenthesis. Post your work again here after changes and am sure others will help you if you still stucks.